# Issue in finding Xpath for Mobile App (Blocking my Automation) using Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium, uiautomatorviewer

Please can any one provide me the solution for the below issue

Issue is that i am unable to find the xpath for my mobile app for the particular page and i tried in many ways to fetch the xpath (Even using chrome://inspect/#devices) (Since i am facing this issue after i was unable to capture the screen using uiautomatorviewer, screen was not captured using uiautomatorviewer).

Thanks in advance[Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW0y0.png)

Comment: For which element you are trying to find the xpath? What have you tried?

Comment: are you automation native app or mobile web app ?

Comment: Assuming that this is HTML5 and the application is coded using responsive design, if you open devtools under google chrome you can toggle device toolbar (CTRL+SHIFT+M) and pick a mobile device. The HTML should respond with mobile values.  Just right-click on the element, select Inspect, right-click on the elements under devtools, Copy->Copy Xpath.

Comment: Could you please provide the UIAutomator error you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

As i've encountered a similar issue before, what solved it for me was to close Appium while trying to fetch the page with UIAutomator